# Drop-down navigation menu being overlapped by lower div

Tags: css, hover, drop-down-menu, z-index

Stack,

I'm having difficulty creating a good drop down navigation menu using only css.  The menu is simple, it needs to only have a few things in it, and only needs to drop down (no need to go down and over etc).

The menu is somewhat working, but whenever I hover over it to drop it down, the menu gets overlapped by the wrapper div directly below the header div where the menu is located.  I've tried setting the z-index of the drop down menu to like 20000 and it is still being overlapped.

Here is a direct link to the test page I am working on:

http://www.lolbrary.com/workspace/dropdownheader.php

Any ideas?

Thanky,

billmalarky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `#fullheaderbar` and `#profilemenu` you need to remove `overflow:hidden;` and in `.profile-menu ul` you need to change `position:relative` to `position:absolute;`

then tweak from there :)

Comment: Okay I made you change and that seems to be working.  Yet now a new challenger appears! Take another quick look at the page and you will see that it is pushing the wrapper div down instead of overlapping it.  Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: change position:relative to position:absolute like @Joseph mentioned. You need to to do it on the list of items that drop down. In your html code it is the tag `<ul class>` (you forgot to supply a class name)

Comment: Ah... sorry.  Missed the hover effect.  Change `position:relative` in your `.profile-menu:hover ul` rule to `position:absolute` (lolbrarystyle-workbench.css:326)

Comment: @ImportedNoob, Thank you guys.  I had bunch of crap code that needed to be cleaned up where I placed position relative on a ton of classes last night in a hope to fix it by throwing mud against a wall until it stuck.  Some of these where overriding my position absolutes so I deleted them all and it seems to be working now.  Just need to tweak ftw! Thank you for the quick and helpful responses guys.

Comment: @Joseph Thank you guys. I had bunch of crap code that needed to be cleaned up where I placed position relative on a ton of classes last night in a hope to fix it by throwing mud against a wall until it stuck. Some of these where overriding my position absolutes so I deleted them all and it seems to be working now. Just need to tweak ftw! Thank you for the quick and helpful responses guys.

Comment: No problem. I'm scared of lists as navigation items for this reason :p

Comment: @ImportedNoob Okay so I'm almost done with the list, but there is one final issue.  When you hover over the top link it pull severything up fine, but when you hover over the logout link below it I can't get the border-bottom: 0px to stick to the top link so it creates a line in between the links.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Joseph Okay so I'm almost done with the list, but there is one final issue. When you hover over the top link it pull severything up fine, but when you hover over the logout link below it I can't get the border-bottom: 0px to stick to the top link so it creates a line in between the links. Thoughts?

Comment: Try to set the border to 0px during one of the :hover classes.

Comment: Will changing the border to 0px in .profile-menu ul help?

Try to add the !important identified next to the 0px border css

Comment: @billmalarky this one is a little harder to test, but I think the problem is with this rule: `.profile-menu a.profile-button:hover, .profile-menu a.profile-button.hover`. change the first selector to go off of the `.profile-menu:hover` instead, so your rule would look like this: `.profile-menu:hover a.profile-button, .profile-menu a.profile-button.hover`. I *think* that'll fix it. (line:286)

Comment: I think this has something to do with position: absolute. The billmalarky menu dropdown item has a relative position and the menu items have an absolute position. I think that once you have from a relative to an absolute, you lost focus on the relative, so the hover styles are no longer being applied.

Comment: @ImportedNoob it has everything to do with his :hover rule.  Currently it's applied to the anchor tag. Once you hover over the submenu, the rue disappears.  Changing the hover trigger to the parent menu item (rather than the anchor) should fix it.

Comment: @joseph Sorry guys, I hadn't checked for updates since importednoob said "Try to set the border to 0px during one of the :hover classes." However, I did solve the problem on my own. Joseph was correct from what I surmise, in that I needed to apply the hover rules to a class that was a parent to both the top level link "billmalarky" and the drop down ul that was in a li directly below the top level link.  I just placed them both inside a li element and hover styled the master li element. That way when I hovered over the ul inside the master li element, I was (comment continued in next comment!)

Comment: @ImportedNoob (comment continued from previous comment) That way when I hovered over the ul inside the master li element, I was technically still hovering over the top level link that was also in the master li element. I'll leave the page up for a few days if you want to take a quick look to better your own knowledge of css. Thanks again for all your help.